# 'Segment fault' when calculating the elapsed time using std::chrono

Tags: c++, c++11

I changed [this code](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/cpp-timer-raii/) and have written this function:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#define TIMER(name) Timer timer__(name);
class Timer
{
public:

    Timer(const std::string& name) :
            name_(name), start_(std::chrono::system_clock::now())
    {
    }

    ~Timer()
    {
        auto duration = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start_;
        std::cout << std::setw(90) << std::left << name_ << ": " <<  std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(duration).count() << "s" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::string name_ = 0;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start_ ;
};
```

The problem is that sometimes I get segment fault.

usage:

put something like this in the main():

```
TIMER("Total time");
```

I compiled the program with gcc version 5.2.1.

Comment: Where and when? and how do you use this class?

Comment: I use this class extensively. Some times that my program take long time, I am getting segment fault.

Comment: Why not use gettimeofday() and the timeval struct?

Comment: I want to use the standard library.

Comment: @PM why use `gettimeofday()` if you can use `std::chrono`?

Comment: @user1436187: do you have a backtrace?

Comment: No, unfortunately I cannot simulate the issue. This is exactly my main problem.

Comment: @JoelCornett Because I've never known gettimeofday() to seg fault.

Comment: Most likely some memory corruption, probably unrelated to this class (but close to the Timer object that segfaults). Try to run it under valgrind. You can try a short run first, the error might only cause the segfault under certain circumstances, but be detectable much earlier.

Comment: You should remove `= 0` from `std::string name_ = 0;`. If the default member initialiser ever gets used, `std::string` will read the `0` as a pointer to a null terminated sequence of characters; and since this is a null pointer, attempting to dereference it will have undefined behaviour. (There is nothing in your example that will lead to that happening, but the `= 0` will either do nothing, or have undefined behaviour, so it should be removed).

Comment: @user1436187: I agree with @eran. I find it unlikely that there is a actually a problem with `duration::count()`.

Comment: Why do you think the segfault is related to your timer at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two remarks:
1. as mentioned by @Mankarse, remove `= 0;` from `std::string name_ = 0;`
2. From [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3):

> Each identifier that contains a double underscore __ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use.

So change `Timer timer__(name)` to something like `Timer my_timer(name)`